# How to traverse XML string C#?

Tags: c#, xml

I want to traverse the below XML string and want to Mask the **AcctNum** tag and return the masked string. Masking like **************5411

```
<Response Version="3" xmlns="http">
 <RespClientID>
  <DID>*************</DID>
  <ClientRef>********</ClientRef>
 </RespClientID>
 <Status StatusCode="OK"></Status>
 <TransactionResponse>
  <ReturnCode>000</ReturnCode>
  <Payload><?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><GMF xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/abc" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/" xmlns="com/"><CreditResponse><CommonGrp><PymtType>Credit</PymtType><TxnType>ABC</TxnType><LocalDateTime>12345</LocalDateTime><TrnmsnDateTime>123</TrnmsnDateTime><STAN>123</STAN><RefNum>123</RefNum><OrderNum>306305490</OrderNum><TermID>00000001</TermID><MerchID>123</MerchID><TxnAmt>298</TxnAmt><TxnCrncy>840</TxnCrncy></CommonGrp><CardGrp><AcctNum>1234543212345411</AcctNum><AVSResultCode>Y</AVSResultCode></CardGrp><VisaGrp><ACI>W</ACI><CardLevelResult>H</CardLevelResult><SourceReasonCode>6</SourceReasonCode><TransID>123</TransID><TaxAmtCapablt>TX</TaxAmtCapablt></VisaGrp><RespGrp><RespCode>000</RespCode><AuthID>OK7898</AuthID><AddtlRespData>APPROVAL</AddtlRespData><AthNtwkID>02</AthNtwkID><AthNtwkNm>VISA</AthNtwkNm></RespGrp></CreditResponse></GMF></Payload>
 </TransactionResponse>
</Response>
```

Comment: Your xml is invalid. Xml cannot contain declaration `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>` inside body.

Comment: What did you try so far? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Ignoring the correct observation of Alexander: You may want to try [XSL-Transformation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/data/xml/xslt-transformations). You could easily write one that filters the text content of the respective nodes. Then actually masking is merely a one-liner.

Comment: @Fildor: According to the URL in your comment: _The XslTransform class is obsolete in .NET Framework version 2.0. The XslCompiledTransform class is a new implementation of the XSLT engine_

Comment: Ah. I might have mixed up the links. @user09938 But the point still is that xslt might help.